# Form not sending to Apple Email Accounts

Tags: php, email

Okay this is an odd one, and I seem to remember it happening before but can't remember the fix...

My form will send to all other email accounts but not Apple accounts (@icloud.com, @mac.com, @me.com). If I remove all other email addresses and have it ONLY sending to 1 Apple account it goes. But as soon as other emails are listed it sends to only them and not the Apple accounts (spam, junk etc all checked too).

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = “***”;
$password = “***”;
$dbname = “***”;


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO guestquestionnaire (date_submitted, choice, expectations)
    VALUES (:date_submitted, :choice, :expectations)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':date_submitted', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':choice', $choice);
    $stmt->bindParam(':expectations', $expectations);


    // insert a row
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $choice = $_POST['choice'];
    $expectations = $_POST['expectations'];

    }


catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;



?>



<?php

$my_email = "email@gmail.com";


$errors = array();

// Remove $_COOKIE elements from $_REQUEST.

if(count($_COOKIE)){foreach(array_keys($_COOKIE) as $value){unset($_REQUEST[$value]);}}

// Check all fields for an email header.

function recursive_array_check_header($element_value)
{

global $set;

if(!is_array($element_value)){if(preg_match("/(%0A|%0D|\n+|\r+)(content-type:|to:|cc:|bcc:)/i",$element_value)){$set = 1;}}
else
{

foreach($element_value as $value){if($set){break;} recursive_array_check_header($value);}

}

}

recursive_array_check_header($_REQUEST);

if($set){$errors[] = "You cannot send an email header";}

unset($set);



// Check referrer is from same site.

if(!(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))){$errors[] = "You must enable referrer logging to use the form";}

// Check for a blank form.

function recursive_array_check_blank($element_value)
{

global $set;

if(!is_array($element_value)){if(!empty($element_value)){$set = 1;}}
else
{

foreach($element_value as $value){if($set){break;} recursive_array_check_blank($value);}

}

}

recursive_array_check_blank($_REQUEST);

if(!$set){$errors[] = "You cannot send a blank form";}

unset($set);

// Display any errors and exit if errors exist.

if(count($errors)){foreach($errors as $value){print "$value<br>";} exit;}

if(!defined("PHP_EOL")){define("PHP_EOL", strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == "WIN") ? "\r\n" : "\n");}

// Build message.


            $message = '<html><body>';  
            $message .=  "<strong>Questionnaire </strong>";
            $message .=  "<strong>Received: </strong>";
            $message .=  "<P>";

            $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border: 1px solid #999;" cellpadding="7" width="100%" >';

            $message .= "<tr style='background: #566890; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><td colspan='3'>Prior to Arrival</td></tr>";



            $message .= "<tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>What made you choose us? </td><td width='40%' colspan='2'>" . strip_tags($_POST['choice']) . "</td></tr>";

            $message .= "<tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>Did we meet your expectations as advertised? If no, please state why: </td><td width='40%' colspan='2'>" . strip_tags($_POST['expectations']) . "</td></tr>";


            $message .= "</table>";

            $message .= "</body></html>";





            //   CHANGE THE BELOW VARIABLES TO YOUR NEEDS

            $to = 'email@gmail.com, email@personalemail.com, email@mac.com,  email@icloud.com';

            $subject = 'Questionnaire Received';

            $headers = "From: email@gmail.com\r\n”;
            $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))

?>

</head>
```

EDIT: I should also add that  if the FROM field

```
$headers = "From: email@icloud.com"
```

is my iCloud account it does go through that iCloud account and the other non Apple account users. Other iCloud accounts won't get it though.

Also, for those that do get it, they can see the iCloud email accounts in the list of who it was sent to; they just don't get them.

Comment: What do the mail logs tell you? Do you see a bunch of 550 errors?

Comment: This might seem silly, but where are the mail logs?

Comment: Okay, got into my mail logs. Can't see anything obvious. It lists the email addresses under remote-handlers. Everything looks like it should of gone through though

Comment: I should also add that if the FROM - $headers = "From: email@icloud.com" is my iCloud account it does go through that iCloud account and the other non Apple account users (other iCloud accounts won't get it though).

Comment: Also, for those that do get it, they can see the iCloud email accounts in the list of who it was sent to; they just don't get them.